# Geth Blockchain synchronised issue

Tags: blockchain, ether, geth-debugging, geth-clique

i am developing my private Blockchain using geth. I am created successfully my private Blockchain and created native coin on that, after that I created RPC URL for metamask later I am transfer some coins from my main node to Metamask wallet address and its successful transfer and coin showing in Metamask wallet but problem is when I check transaction status on node then its shows null, How to solve this issues

when miner node restart then its working for some hours